# how to convert a charcter string to a name that accepts data (data frame name) in R

Tags: r

I have stored a list of names as characters  and want to convert them to something that can be accepted as data frame name. something like this:

```
for (i in 1:18) {
    str[i] <- paste("alert_month_amount_",i,sep="")
}
name_str = as.character(str)
```

then name_str will be:

`name_str[1]` would be `"alert_month_amount_1"`

now i want to assign certain data to a data frame that uses name_str[i] inside a loop like:

```
for (n in 1:18){
  name_str[n] <- subset(by_Month_Acct_Num,month==month_index[n] & year==year_index[n])
}
```

but this does not work perhaps because the names are passed as characters inside double quotation mark ("). I would appreciate your help.

Comment: There's almost never a real need to do this in R. Rather than programmatically building variable names, you should probably be storing related items in lists. you can then easily apply functions over elements of the list. If you are an R beginner and you're using `paste()` with `assign()` or `get()`, that's usually a sign you are not doing things the "R way".

Comment: @MrFlick What is the advantage of putting these things into a list, instead? How would you go about naming them, within the list, in the way @amin ahmadi would like? Why isn't `assign` the `R` way? 

Thanks!

Comment: One advantage is that you won't have 18 different variables names for similar variables  cluttering the global environment.  With a list you won't have any trouble finding them later because they're all in the same place

Comment: There's not good reason to have a bunch of variables like `alert_month_amount_1` and `alert_month_amount_2` and `alert_month_amount_3` etc, especially if all the values are of similar structure. It's better to have something like `alert_month_amount <- list(5, 10, 15)` and then extract elements like `alert_month_amount[[1]]`, `alert_month_amount[[2]]`, etc. Then you can use functions like `sapply()` and `lapply()` to form operations across all the related objects. It makes vectorization much easier and that's one of the friendliest benefits of using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` for this:

```
assign(name_str[n], subset(by_Month_Acct_Num,month==month_index[n] & year==year_index[n]))
```

Comment: This is probably not the best way to introduce someone to R programming. You will end up littering their workspaces with such names and then they have difficulty accessing them. There won't be any way of telling how many there are and the looping needed to do anything with them will be inefficient. Please listen to MrFlick and demonstrate how to properly use R lists.

Comment: I'm not convinced. The object names are stored in name_str and they can viewed with `ls()`. What exactly is the problem with 'littering the workspace'?

Comment: You can view them with ls() which will return not the objects but a character vector. You will then need to use `get` or `mget` every time you want to access them singly or as a group. It's simply painful to look at such code.

Answer (score 1):

This is [FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).  The most important part of that answer is the end where it says (like @MrFlick) that it is better to use a list.  You really should learn how to take advantage of R's vectorized functions.

The `paste` and `paste0` functions are both vectorized, so your first bit of code can be replaced with:

```
name_str <- paste0("alert_month_amount_", 1:18)
```

without need for the loop.

You could create your list and fill it with code like:

```
alert_month_amount <- list()
for(i in 1:18) {
  alert_month_amount[[i]] <- subset(by_Month_Acct_Num,month==month_index[n] & year==year_index[n])
}
```

Or possibly even easier using the `split` function.  You could also use `lapply` or `mapply`.

If you want the elements named then just do:

```
names(alert_month_amount) <- name_str
```

Now with everything in a single list you can copy, save, delete, etc. one object rather than needing another loop to do each individual piece.  If you want to do the same thing (calculate a summary, fit a regression, etc.) on each piece created then with everything in a list you can just use `lapply` or `sapply` on the list rather than having to create another loop and figuring out how to grab each piece in the loop and save it to an output object.